# Dropdown menu text doesn't display when set a default value - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a select menu.

```
<select id="dd" ng-show='data != null' ng-model='search'></select>
```

I triggered the filter to USA as default

```
$scope.search = 'United States of America';
```

So far the filter seem to work, but none of my jQuery seem to work.

```
$scope.search = 'United States of America';
$("#dd").val('United States of America');
$("#dd").attr("selected","selected");
```

You may see what I have here : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0xj47wax/1/)

---

Result now :

[image]

Result I want it to be :

[image]

**What else I should look into to debug this further ?**

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I would do like this-

In your angular controller

```
$scope.timeFrames = [{ "id": 1, "name": "USA" }, { "id": 2, "name": "UK" }, { "id": 3, "name": "China" }];
$scope.selectedTimeFrame = 1;
```

In you html page

```
 <select ng-model="selectedTimeFrame" ng-change="frame()" ng-options="timeFrame.id as timeFrame.name for timeFrame in timeFrames" ng-cloak></select>
```

Trying to control the select drop down through java script is not the correct way to do. In angular, we have ng-options, Please refer to this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

Comment: Can you please update your answer and explain in details a little bit ?

Comment: Please refer to this [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) about ng-options